# Datagridview Windows application API call on Scroll

Tags: c#, datagridview, windows

There is bulk data to be retrieved from the database and show it on the datagridview.
I use API(Asmx) methods to get the data.
I want to load data(call api) as the user scrolls down the grid.
I dont want to get all the data at form load itself.

I have API's to get partial data. How do i call this api when user scrolls down and bind the grid as keeps scrolling?

Its quite a challenge.. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `VirtualMode` for the `DataGridView`.  Check out this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode.aspx) which explains why it is good for your bulk data.

> Virtual mode is designed for use with very large stores of data. When the VirtualMode property is true, you create a DataGridView with a set number of rows and columns and then handle the CellValueNeeded event to populate the cells. Virtual mode requires implementation of an underlying data cache to handle the population, editing, and deletion of DataGridView cells based on actions of the user. For more information about implementing virtual mode, see How to: Implement Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control.

There is also a tutorial on setting this up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: No problem!  =)  I had to take over a project that utilized this stuff.  Interesting to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

C.Barlow - Has provided a good solution which works fine. I would also like to put down an alternate solution.

On DataGridView Scroll Event we can load data, as the user scrolls down and reaches the bottom of the grid.

```
private void Grid_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
       if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.SmallIncrement || e.Type ==  ScrollEventType.LargeIncrement)
         {
               if (e.NewValue >= Grid.Rows.Count - GetDisplayedRowsCount())
               {
              //Load additional data here and add to your existing grid rows
//Keep track of last visible row and set it
                }
          }
}
```

//GetDisplayedRowsCount() will give you the rowcount. Simple function to get rowcount